# Something is going horribly wrong with my linked list code

Tags: c++, list, pointers

I'm brushing up my C++ coding skills for an interview and I'm trying to understand the error in this code I wrote for a linked list

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *next;
} *Head ;

void ListInit()
{
  Head = NULL;
}

void addfront(Node *Head, int data)
{
    Node *newnode = new Node;
    newnode->data = data;
    newnode->next = Head;
    Head = newnode;
}

void displaylist(Node *Head)
{
    Node *cur;
    cur = Head;
    if(cur==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"List is Empty ! ";
    }

    while(cur->next!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<"  "<<cur->data<<"  ";
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    ListInit();
    addfront(Head,5);
    addfront(Head,6);
    addfront(Head,8);
    addfront(Head,1);
    addfront(Head,9);

    displaylist(Head);
    return 0;
}
```

Codeblocks crashes when I run this, so I'm guessing its a segmentation fault. But I can't figure out why its creeping into this.

Comment: Apart from new instead of malloc and cout instead of printf, this is C.

Comment: In `addfront` you are only modifying a local copy of `Head`.

Comment: @NeilKirk: So? That means it's still C++.

Comment: This is why i use `g_` for global variables

Comment: @Deduplicator I would expect a C++ job would expect a class for this problem, otherwise it's a C job.

Comment: @NeilKirk C++ is C++ and not C, whether you do full TMP or low-level bit-munging.

Comment: @Deduplicator This is a pointless argument because you miss my point. I am making the OP aware that he may not be brushing up the right things for a C++ interview.

Comment: I think we should agree to disagree then. Because imho basic pointer-manipulation is a neccessary fundamental skill, for C++ as much as for C. That's even though this rationale for your comment was not terribly obvious...

Comment: @Deduplicator If I wanted to brush up my C++ skills and basic pointer-manipulation, I would still create a class for the linked list.

Comment: @NeilKirk: Ok, one could (and should, for C++) wrap it in a class-template, parameterized on the element-type. As long as you don't insist on bolting all kind of gizmos onto the Node-POD, you might have a point then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Itjax** already answered your question but apart from that change which Itjax suggested you also need to change this:

```
if(cur==NULL)
{
    cout<<"List is Empty ! ";
}
```

**To:**

```
if(cur==NULL)
{
    cout<<"List is Empty ! ";
    return;
}
```

Otherwise when your list is empty your code will crash again.

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is that you are only modifying copies of your Head pointer in addFront. Try to change the original by making it a reference:

```
void addfront(Node*& Head, int data) // note the extra &
{
    Node *newnode = new Node;
    newnode->data = data;
    newnode->next = Head;
    Head = newnode;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ltjax are right. In function addfront() you change the value of the local variable Head, which has the same name as a global. Do not do that! This is a very bad style. 
Also, that the application does not fall, then the function displaylist() reacts as something else than display the message. Use return after the conclusion of the message:

```
if (cur == NULL) 
{
    cout << "List is Empty!"; 
    return; 
}
```

Or go on to cycle along the branch else:

```
if (cur == NULL)
{
    cout << "List is Empty!";
}
else
{
    while (cur-> next! = NULL)
    {
        cout << "" << cur-> data << "";
        cur = cur-> next;
    }
}
```